# What is the solution for $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\left(\cos\frac xm\right)^{m}$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Please, help me in solving of $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\left(\cos\frac xm\right)^{m}$.

Comment: l'Hôpital's rule

Comment: Just notice this $\cos(\frac{x}{m})\sim 1$ as $ m\to \infty $.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal *Just notice this*... Exactly the mistake to avoid. Note that $1\sim1$, $1+1/m\sim1$ and $1+1/\sqrt{m}\sim1$ while $1^m\to1$, $(1+1/m)^m\to\mathrm e$ and $(1+1/\sqrt{m})^m\to\infty$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I thought about it, but $1^\infty$ is still indeterminate in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approximation $\cos(x)\approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ (which has several geometric proofs) and the binomial approximation $(1+t)^n\approx 1+nt$ are enough to give you $\displaystyle\left(\cos\frac{x}{m}\right)^m\approx\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2m^2}\right)^m\approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2m}$, and of course taking the limit as $m\to\infty$ in the latter expression is trivial.

Comment: $1\approx 2$ but they don't have equal limits.

Comment: Nice and fine answer +1

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese That depends entirely on what your usage of $\approx$ is.  I'm (informally and implicitly) using a version in which $a\approx b+c$ stands for $a=b+c+o(c)$; it's easy to formalize these manipulations and for a proof one would obviously want to be a lot more careful than I was here, but for a problem this simple I felt the extra notation just gets in the way.

Comment: Of course, I should have made myself a bit clearer. I wasn't doubting your method, I just thought the use of the symbol $\approx$ doesn't make it clear that the approximations need to be fairly good ones (in the sense that you have made clear in your comment).

Answer (score 2):

Another way
$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\left(\cos\frac xm-1\right)\right)^{m}=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\exp{\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\cos\frac xm-1\right)}{\displaystyle\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)^2}\times \displaystyle\frac{x^2}{m}\right)}=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\exp{\left(\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{x^2}{m}\right)}=\exp(0)=1$$

Done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 1.
Try taylor expanding cos and using $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\log({1+x})}{x}=1$.

Comment: Thank you! But is there a possibility to solve it without using 
l'Hôpital's rule or Taylor expanding, i.e. using trigonometric identities?

Comment: Well, instead of taylor expanding you can use                  $cos(2x)=1-2sin^2(x)$ and $ lim_{x\to 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x}=1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\Big(\cos\frac{x}{m}\Big)^m=\left(1+\frac{m\big(\cos\frac{x}{m}-1\big)}{m}\right)^m$$

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}m\big(\cos\frac{x}{m}-1\big)=x\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{x}{m} -\cos0}{\frac{x}{m}}=x\cos'(0)=0$$

Thus $$\Big(\cos\frac{x}{m}\Big)^m\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty} e^{\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}m\big(\cos\frac{x}{m}-1\big)}=1$$