# Help with a limit for $\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to solve the next limit but without using derivatives, so only using the properties for sequences, so we can't use l'Hopital , we can't use Taylor series or more advanced analysis, only properties of sequences.

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n$$

What we tried a transformation like using logarithm

$$ e^{n \cdot \ln(\cos(1/n))} $$

and then

$$ e^{\frac{\ln(\cos(1/n))}{1/n}} $$

so we need to solve

$$ \frac{\ln(\cos(1/n))}{1/n} $$

And here I am stuck, CesaroStolz did not work

Second idea is to rewrite it like

$$ \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$

when n goes to infinity is equal to

$$ e^{\ln\left(1 - \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}} $$

$$ e^{\frac{n}{2} \ln\left(1 - \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)} $$

$$ e^{\frac{1}{2} \frac{\ln\left(1 - \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}} $$

My idea was that maybe we could apply some sin and ln formulas but it does not work in this case.

Edit: Here is my solution, not sure if is correct, but it does not use l'Hopital and I included all the steps to be much clear then the other question anwers

$$ \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$

We have this relations

$$
\tag{1}
\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{{\ln(1 + x)}}{x} = 1
$$
this implies
$$ \tag{2}
\ln(1+ x) \approx x \quad \text{when} \ x \text{ is close to } 0
$$

$$\tag{3}
\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 1
$$

so we get

$$\tag{4}
\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) -1 = 0
$$

So to solve $$ \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$
first we will use the ln to push the n from the exponent down

$$ e^{\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)} $$

$$ e^{ n \ln\left(1 + \cos\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) -1 \right)} $$

$$\tag{5}  e^{ \frac{\ln\left(1 + \cos\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) -1 \right)}{\frac{1}{n}}} $$

From the equalites at 2 and 4. we get

$$\tag{6} \ln\left(1 + \cos\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) -1 \right) \approx \cos\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) -1 $$

Using the relation 6 in 5 we get rid of the ln

$$ \tag{7} e^{\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) -1}{\frac{1}{n}}}  $$

From
$$
 \cos(0) = 1
$$

To find $$\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - 1$$

Using the identity
$$
 \(\cos(a) - \cos(b) = -2 \sin\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)\), substitute \(a = \frac{1}{n}\) and \(b = 0\) $$

$$
\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - 1 = -2 \sin\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n}+0}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n}-0}{2}\right)
$$

Simplify further:

$$ \tag{8}
\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - 1 = -2 \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) 
$$

From 7 and 8 we need to find the limit for
$$
\frac{-2 \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{1/n} = 
\frac{- \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{1/2n} =
\frac{- \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2} \times \frac{1}{2n} =
\rightarrow -1 \times 0 = 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \rightarrow \infty
$$

Comment: Hint: as $x\to0,$ $\ln(\cos x)=\ln(1-x^2/2+o(x^2))\sim-x^2/2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval the aproximation from your first comment is not in the manual so we can't use that. The other question answers use derivatives, Taylor or some other approximation. Second answer though  seems to be the one I need but I do not understand it, soem steps are missing https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285095/1273649  or I am missing some obvious equality.  Thank you for the help

Comment: The answer you linked to uses exactly the same two approximations as in my first comment, namely (as $h\to0$): $\ln(1+h)\sim h$ and $(\cos h)-1\sim-h^2/2$. Are you forbidden to use both, or is one of them allowed? Anyway, they can be justified directly (without L'Hopital) simply by definition of the derivative as a limit: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=\ln'(1)=1$$ and $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(\cos h)-1}{h^2}=-2\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h/2)}h\right)^2=-\frac12(\sin'(0))^2=-\frac12.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval we can use the qualities you listed, they can be proven withour derivatives.  I do not understand the first  = in that solution i linked, I do not see how the left side   is tranformed into the right side , here are my attempts

$$ \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$

$$ e^{\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)} $$

$$ e^{ n \ln\left(1 + \cos\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) -1 \right)} $$

$$ e^{ \frac{\ln\left(1 + \cos\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) -1 \right)}{\frac{1}{n}}} $$

Comment: Here is how these two asymptotic approximations are used: for $x$ fixed and $m\to\infty$, since $\cos\frac xm-1\to0$,
$$m\ln\left(1+\left(\cos\frac xm-1\right)\right)\sim m\left(\cos\frac xm-1\right)=\frac{\cos\frac xm-1}{\left(\frac xm\right)^2}\times\frac{x^2}m$$
and since $\frac xm\to0$,
$$\frac{\cos\frac xm-1}{\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)^2}\to-\frac12.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval thx, I do not understand why your above limit is not 0 since you multiply with x^2 /m  at the end.

Comment: ¿ The limit of the exponent *is* $0$, like in the answer you linked.

Comment: @AnneBauva lthank you,  I did not seen that limit that goes to 1/2 , I am not sure if I should have it in my memory. I edited my question with a solution(appended it at the end) I managed to create using a bit of trigonometry,  looks correct to me.

Comment: Well done! What you essentially proved (and should "have in your memory" I think) is: $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}=-\frac12.$$ And for this you proved a formula which is also useful to remember. $$\cos(2t)=\cos^2t-\sin^2t=2\cos^2t-1=1-2\sin^2t.$$